# How to grab data from inputDataGroup from a url

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to grab some data from a url. My code does not work as it produces error.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:92.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/92.0"}
r = requests.get('https://bscscan.com/tx/0x6cf01dda40e854b47117bb51c8d2148c6ae851e7d79d792867d1fa66d5ba6bad', headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')


test = soup.find('div', class_='rawtab').get_text()
print (test)
```

Wanted Output:

```
Function: lockTokens(address _token, address _withdrawer, uint256 _amount, uint256 _unlockTimestamp) ***

MethodID: 0x7d533c1e
[0]:  000000000000000000000000109fddb8d49ae139449cb061883b685827b23937
[1]:  000000000000000000000000d824567e3821e99e90930a84d3e320a0fdb6f867
[2]:  00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a768da96dc82245ed943
[3]:  00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000628d8187
```

Current Output:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your near to your goal, but have to switch the attribute type.

```
<div data-target-group="inputDataGroup" id="rawtab">
```

The `<div>` do not contain a `class` it is the `id` you should select and more specific its `textarea`:

```
soup.find('div', id='rawtab').textarea.text
```

or with `css selector`:

```
soup.select_one('div#rawtab textarea').text
```

##### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:92.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/92.0"}
r = requests.get('https://bscscan.com/tx/0x6cf01dda40e854b47117bb51c8d2148c6ae851e7d79d792867d1fa66d5ba6bad', headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')


test = soup.select_one('div#rawtab textarea').text
print (test)
```

##### Output

```
Function: lockTokens(address _token, address _withdrawer, uint256 _amount, uint256 _unlockTimestamp) ***

MethodID: 0x7d533c1e
[0]:  000000000000000000000000109fddb8d49ae139449cb061883b685827b23937
[1]:  000000000000000000000000d824567e3821e99e90930a84d3e320a0fdb6f867
[2]:  00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a768da96dc82245ed943
[3]:  00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000628d8187
```

---

Getting the items as list:

```
textArea = soup.select_one('div#rawtab textarea').text.split('\r\n')
data = [n.split()[-1] for n in textArea if ']:' in n]
```

Output `data` (you can pick by index):

```
['000000000000000000000000109fddb8d49ae139449cb061883b685827b23937',
 '000000000000000000000000d824567e3821e99e90930a84d3e320a0fdb6f867',
 '00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a768da96dc82245ed943',
 '00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000628d8187']
```